# Fscanf inside while keeps crashing?

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I have the following text:

```
ASDCASDSA255878 Jack Jhon 1988 12
ASDCASDSA255878 Bill Smith 1977 12
```

And i have the following code:

```
inputFile = fopen(fileName,"r");
char id[50];
char fname[50];
char lname[50];
char year[50];
char month[50];
while(fscanf(inputFile, "%s %s %s %s %s\n",id,fname,lname,year,month) == 5)
{

}
fclose(inputFile);
```

The file gets opened and if i put a printf statment inside the while loop i could see it and after that it crashes.

I tried changing the `==5` to `!=EOF` but same problem.

Comment: Please provide a full (but short) code example (with `main()` and `#include`). Is your full input just the 2 lines above, or is there more?

Comment: You should never read unbounded data into buffers. Say something like `%49s` or so to be safe.

Comment: Most likely the `filename` contains some data with more than 50 chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the words in the input are longer than 50 characters.

The easiest way to check this is to temporarily change all occurrences of `[50]` in your code to the input file size, so it will be large enough.